# navigator.onLine is not working in my mobile.How to check internet is online.offline??? In Phonegap

Tags: cordova, navigator

I am using phonegap for my app. My app is basicaly for RSS_FEED from one website.
but my requirement is when internet is not there application should `alert`-`offline`.

when application run on online all data stored into database.
and when internet is not there that time data fetched from DB so my problem is only that application shows me online every time while using of `navigator.onLine`.

```
if(navigator.onLine) {
    alert("check online");
    loadScript("http://www.google.com/jsapi",msgOnFn)
    loadScript("js/googleapi.js", msgOnFn);
} else {
    loadScript("js/db.js",msgOffFn);
}
```

I tried [THIS ALSO](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_connection_connection.md.html)
In this it shows **none** or **wifi** everytime. I am not getting why this happening.

in web browser,It is working fine. :)

Comment: Look at this, this worked for me!! <br/>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30482845/navigator-online-not-working-cordova-5-0-0">Stackoverflow Link</a>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please follow the [phonegap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#connection.type).

You could also change the given function to return true or false:

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = false;
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = true;
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = true;
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = true;
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = true;
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = true;
    states[Connection.CELL]     = true;
    states[Connection.NONE]     = false;
    if (states[networkState]) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: in that it showing `Cannot read property 'connection' of undefined`
I am using cordovo 2.0.0.js

Comment: _Before Cordova 2.3.0, the Connection object existed at: navigator.network.connection._

So you have to change the following line:
`var networkState = navigator.connection.type;` to `var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;`

Comment: that is returning `UNKNOWN` or `UNDEFINED`

Comment: Check the phonegap example for version 2.0.0: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection

Comment: I am stuck at the same issue reproducing this in ionic. Did you solve this by any chance? I am using the latest cordova 3.5.1

Comment: You need to add the [`network-information` plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information) to make this API available.

Comment: In Phonegap, that means adding
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
to config.xml

Comment: The connection.type has been updated on chrome you can access type using navigator.connection.effectiveType  instead of navigator.connection.type