# navigator.onLine not working cordova 5.0.0

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am having problems with checking if a device has no internet connection. I am using cordova 5.0.0 CLI. This is my code:

```
if(navigator.onLine) {
  alert("online");
} else {
  alert("offline");
  window.open("404.html");
}
```

The problem is: it's always true. How can i fix it? I know this [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information), but I don't know how I even get it working. I know how to add plugins, but then it ends. Could someone help me getting this plugin working, or an alternative code to check if a user is offline? Thanks in advance

Comment: onLine does not mean it has an internet connection in all devices. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448591/navigator-online-is-not-working-in-my-mobile-how-to-check-internet-is-online-off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your index.html :

```
document.addEventListener("offline", function(){ navigator.notification.alert("No connection found") }, false);
```

It will alert you if there isn't a network connection.

If you don't have the notification plugin :

```
document.addEventListener("offline", function(){ alert("No connection found") }, false);
```

Answer (score 3):

Cordova plugins create a bridge between your web app and the native apis of the mobile OS. In order to use the native side you have to wait until cordova is ready. If you want to check whether the user is online or offline you can add the plugin linked in your question and then use it like this:

First create a function that will return `true` or `false` depending if the user is online or not:

```
function checkConnection(){
   var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

   var states = {};
   states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
   states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
   states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
   states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
   states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
   states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
   states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
   states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

   if(states[networkState].indexOf("WiFi") != -1 || states[networkState].indexOf("Cell") != -1)
        return true;
  return false;
}
```

When you get the device ready event:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
   // Now safe to use device APIs
   var connected = checkConnection();//will return true or false

   if(connected){
      //user is online
   }else{
      //user is offline
   }
}
```

Also you can listen directly for `online` and `offline` events like this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
// Now safe to use device APIs
  document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
  document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
}

function onOnline() {
   // User is Online
}
function onOffline() {
   // User is Offline
}
```

Both approaches requires to add the `network-information` plugin. Read the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

add "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information" to your project then use

```
if(windows.navigation.onLine){ 
    alert('online!');
 }
```

also check if this was added to you config.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```