# Check Phonegap app connection

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm doing an non-native app in Phonegap and I want to know when I have connection or not. Searching on the WEB, I found a way of how to know if I get a connection in my app, but I implemented in my code and doesn't worked.

The way I found was this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);  

        // PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods  
        function onDeviceReady() {  
            check_my_Connection();  
        }  

        function check_my_Connection() {  
            var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;  

            var states = {};  
            states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';  
            states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';  
            states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';  
            states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';  
            states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';  
            states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';  
            states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';  

            alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);  
        }
```

And I call the function `onDeviceReady()` in the `ready` function of my script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){
          /*other code*/
          onDeviceReady();
         /*other chode*/
     });

     /*other code functions*/
     /*Before the rest of the code, I added the snippet code above of this*/

     document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
     ...
</script>
```

I read that I need a `cordova.js`, but the [PhoneGap Desktop App](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/03/02/phonegap-app-desktop-0-1-2/) (beta version) doesn't created it. This JS file is required to do this work? Exist another way to detect the connection in the Phonegap apps, without using jQueryUI or jQueryMobile? I need to do some change (s) in some file (s) of my project?

I'll appreciate any help or any way to do this.

P. S.: excuse me for my english.

Comment: I've answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30482845/navigator-online-not-working-cordova-5-0-0/30483272#30483272

Comment: @BipBip Where can I locate this line: `document.addEventListener("offline", function(){ alert("No connection found") }, false);`

Comment: You can put it wherever you want in your html page

Comment: This worked for me, try this!! <br/>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30482845/navigator-online-not-working-cordova-5-0-0">Link</a>

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to be inside your code. Just do the following to receive the connection state:

1. Open up your terminal/console
2. `cordova create networkInformation com.example.com networkInformation`
3. `cd networkInformation`
4. `cordova platform add android`
5. `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information`
6. `cordova build`

After you finished this process, you open up the created folder on your desktop. Move inside the `www` folder inside the `platform` -> `android` folder under `assets`. Open your index.js which should look like this:

```
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }

};

app.initialize();
```

So now look for

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},
```

And change it to this:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    checkConnection();
},
```

Also add

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}
```

directly above `app.initialize();`

This should be your full index.js then. Just launch your application and it'll alert you your network state:

```
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        checkConnection();
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }

};

function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}


app.initialize();
```

Comment: I'm not using the console to create the project, I'm using the Phonegap Desktop App, but I understand that when I create the app this is created with all the files to work well (I suppose). I check the `index,js` file, is the same as you show me, but the last line is not present (`app.initialize()` is located into my `index.html`. I checked my `config.xml` and I have the line `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"/>`. With this is enough to test the connectivity in my app?